# Comunicate with remote Serial over TCP/IP as /dev/ttyX device

Tags: tty, serial-port, tcp-ip, socat

I've one serial device on 192.168.x.x:yyyy (where "x" and "y" are real number) and it works correctly. But I want to communicate with this as `/dev/ttyX` device.

I've tested `socat` command but not working correctly

```
$ while true; do
    socat pty,link=/dev/ttyX,raw,echo=0,waitslave tcp:192.168.x.x:yyyy; 
done
```

How can I resolve?

#### update

- I think that I must be creating a virtual serial device. VIRTUAL SERIAL DEVICE <-> SERIAL-MACHINE-IP:PORT

Comment: Do you mean `/dev/ttySx`?

Comment: yes, in general I want to use remote serial over TCP-IP as classic  Serial Device Path such as /dev/tty.... but I don't know how I can.

Comment: I think that I must be create virtual serial device.

Comment: Please don't change the subject to RESOLVED, revert this Q to just a Q and add an answer if you've solved it yourself. That's completely fine to answer your own Q.

Answer (score 4):

This solved the problem:

```
$ socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/CUSTOMNAME,raw,echo=0,waitslave tcp:192.168.x.x:yyyy;
```

Comment: What is the proper way to create `/dev/CUSTOMNAME`? I get `socat[12316] E symlink("/dev/pts/5", "/dev/MYDEVICE"): Permission denied` when trying to do `sudo socat TCP4-LISTEN:9000,reuseaddr,fork,su=nobody PTY,link=/dev/MYDEVICE,raw,echo=0,waitslave`

Comment: Nevermind; I think the `su=nobody` was the problem. When I removed that it worked.